# Tailwind css design concept and implementation

Tags: css, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

My team manager wants to implement Tailwind CSS for the first time in the project and I am new to tailwind css
The project has some vanilla CSS files so my question is do I need to **write afresh tailwind css stylesheets**  right from the scratch or is there a better solution ..please advise

I tried converting old vanilla css files to tailwind using command npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css but its not helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you mentioned `npx tailwindcss -i input.css -o output.css` is to generate vanilla CSS from tailwindcss's utility classes, not to the reverse.

tailwind, in the end, is just a CSS file and you can have multiple CSS files in your project but to avoid conflicts use [prefix](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration#prefix) Eg: "tw-" in your `tailwind.config.js`, so that it generates classes as `tw-bg-black`

```js
// tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
   prefix: 'tw-',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Tailwind CSS](https://tailwindcss.com/) is a utility first css Framework.

To use it you have to write classes on your elements.

You can keep your old css by importing the old css stylesheets, but if you are using tailwind you should'nt have large CSS stylesheets. It is useless to use tailwind so.

[There is](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation) the official doc to begin with tailwind

Comment: u mean keep old stylesheets using vanilla css format and add new css using tailwind css?

Comment: I mean using both (tailwind and all old stylesheets is useless), if you use tailwind you should write the maximum by using utility-first (classes) of tailwind. And keep the less of your old css stylesheets

Answer (score 0):

Tailwind CSS
if you don't understand how to use it, read the documentation

if not you can add the tailwind css extension if you use,[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqD9f.png) vs code
it will make your job easier